# WCF OData Annotations on POCOs

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

How can I use OData 3.0 property annotations with POCO entity objects in WCF Data Services 5.5?

I'd like to express data validation hints in my entities, such as indicating which properties of an entity are required data. The client may optionally enforce this client-side to save a round trip to the server to find out that a particular field cannot be blank.

My entities are POCOs, not built from EDM.

How are OData property annotations exposed for properties of POCO entities on the client side, and attached to properties of POCO entity on the server side?

If annotations aren't automatically exposed for POCOs, where can I jump in to capture annotation infos so I can associate them with my POCO properties through my own means?